# Rotate Bubble Diagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I've made a bubble diagram with 4 bubbles around the central bubble. But they're in a "cross" appearance, the 4 bubbles are shown in positions N, S, E and W. I'd like to rotate the surrounding bubbles, making them look more like an "X", or, in the positions NE, SE, NW and SW. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, be so kind and show us what  you do so far.  You may find, that drawing it as pure Ti*k*Z picture is the simple way to draw your diagram.

Comment: Can you provide a hand-drawing image ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported natively, but it is also not difficult to get a workaround.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramx}{r[] m}{%
\StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
\IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{bubble diagram}{% true-bubble diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\global\let\maxsmitem\xi%
}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{%true
\node[bubble center node](center bubble){\smitem};
}{%false
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj+\option}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
\node[bubble node] (module\xi) at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem };
}%
}%
\end{tikzpicture}
}{}%end if
}% end command
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramx[bubble diagram:45]{Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Use the `option` part after the type of diagram (e.g., `bubble diagram:45`) to include the shift angle with respect to the original placement.

As requested in the edit, this trick works also for presentation mode:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramanimatedx}{r[] m}{%
\StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
\IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{bubble diagram}{% true-bubble diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\global\let\maxsmitem\xi%
}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{%true
\node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
}{%false
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{360/\actualnumitem*\xj+\option}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
\node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->] (module\xi) at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem };
}%
}%
\end{tikzpicture}
}{}%end if
}% end command
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{example}
\smartdiagramanimatedx[bubble diagram:45]{Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. It was exactly what I was searching for. I was wondering if it would work in an animated smart diagram, to show one bubble each time, in case of a beamer presentation.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosadaSilva: Yes, see the updated reply.

Comment: You really are an exceptional person! As a maintainer of the package, bringing these clarifications is of great relevance to our community. It's awesome to hear directly from the creator of the package. A big thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=red!40]
\node [concept] {Bubble}
    child[grow=45] {node[concept] {Bubble 1}}
    child[grow=135] {node[concept] {Bubble 2}}
    child[grow=225] {node[concept] {Bubble 3}}
    child[grow=-45] {node[concept] {Bubble 4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That aesthetic is awesome! I may think about using it later. Thank you so much,  @Ignasi